# How to encrypt a file using a existing encryption batch file in C# using Processstartinfo?

Tags: batch-file, c#-4.0, encryption, console-application

Can anyone help me how to encrypt a file using a existing encryption script batch file in c# using ProcessStartInfo class?

I am new to the Encryption of a file. I am passing a parameter path, path of text file that I need to encrypt.

This is path of my encryption script batch file

```
      D:\CBMS-Keenan\core\Transmittals\Scripts\123gpg.bat|gpg||false
```

This is my existing code

```
        public string PerformAction(string path)// Path input file name path(.txt)
        {
        //TransmittalBatch batch = new TransmittalBatch();
        string _transmitfile=string.Empty;

        string text1 = "";

        string batchfilename=Path.GetFileName(path);
        string renamedfile = "";
        if((this._filename!=null)&& (this._filename.Length > 0))
        {
            renamedfile = this._filename;
        }
        else
        {
            if(this._replacesuffix)
            {
      renamedfile =   batchfilename.Remove(batchfilename.LastIndexOf("."));

            }
            else
            {
                renamedfile = batchfilename;
            }
            if((this._suffix!=null)&&(this._suffix.Length>0))
            {
                renamedfile = renamedfile + "." + this._suffix.Replace(".", "");
            }
        }
        if ((batchfilename != null) && (batchfilename.Length > 0))
        {
            ProcessStartInfo _info = new ProcessStartInfo(this._scriptfile, "\"" + batchfilename + "\"\"" + renamedfile + "\"");//this._scriptfile is encryprtion batch file //batchfilename is input batch file which we got from the path//renamed file is the filerenamed after the encryption
            _info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            _info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            _info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            _info.RedirectStandardError = true;
            _info.UseShellExecute = false;

            Process _process = Process.Start(_info);
            StreamReader _streamreader1 = _process.StandardOutput;
            StreamReader _streamreader2 = _process.StandardError;
            _process.WaitForExit(300000);
            if(_process.HasExited)
            {
                text1 = _streamreader1.ReadToEnd();
                text1 = text1 + "Errors:\r\n";
                text1 = text1 + _streamreader2.ReadToEnd();
            }
            //batch.RuleActionResults["LatestWorkingFilename"] = text3;
            _process.StandardInput.WriteLine(text1);
            _transmitfile = renamedfile;

        }
        else
        {
            text1 = "No files to encrypt!";
        }
        //batch.RuleActionResults["Encryption Results"] = text1;
        string _ecnryptedfile = text1;
        //Console.WriteLine("Encrypted result:" + _ecnryptedfile);

        return _transmitfile;
        //return batch.RuleActionResults["EncryptionResults"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: So you've got existing code - what happens when you run it? How are we meant to help you without an explanation of the problem? It doesn't help that you haven't explained what the various values involved are or what they're meant to mean, either...

Comment: Check the updates Mr.@JonSkeet..

Comment: I'll add as well "So what happens when you run it?". You get an error, nothing happens, the batch doesn't start, what? The code you posted doesn't help if you don't explain what's wrong

Comment: i need to add the encryption result to a file..